# Sliding in changing text color animation

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm currently working on a website, and trying to come up with a nice menu hover animation.

Sliding the text color from left to right.. If you get what I mean? So AE:

Text color: White
New text color: Black
Duration: 0.5s

But make the animation go from left to right (only the text color, not the background color).

Would this be possible, and does anyone maybe have a solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Only come up with this idea. Hope you get it

```css
p:hover .red{
  color: red;
  transition: 1s;
}

p:hover .green{
  color: red;
  transition: 2s;
}

p:hover .blue{
  color: red;
  transition: 3s;
}
```

```html
<p><span class="red">aa</span><span class="green">aa</span><span class="blue">aa</span></p>
```

Comment: and also you can use delay

Comment: Seems like a pretty cool solution!